# Interact with pseudo-elements with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium Webdriver with Java.
And I was trying to interact with anchor tag which is enclosed as pseudo element ::before

But I am unable to interact with anchor element.
Here is the screenshot of the HTML structure.
[image]

With

`JavaScriptExecutor`, I understand, we can fetch the propertyValue using `window.getComputedStyle().getPropertyValue()` but I am not sure, how to interact with `<a>` element and execute a Click.

Initially, I attempted to click on the Anchor Element without considering the pseudo element as simple Element Interaction.

To fetch the Element:
`private By tabRawView_By_CSS = By.cssSelector("[tabid='raw-view'][role='tab']");` 
[image]

[image]

But this piece is not throwing any error but it is also not clicking on the element.

Then I thought of using JavaScriptExecutor and was trying to run first in Developers Tool as below image but couldn't find suitable options.
[image]

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: tag your binding language, your code attempts and error that you have faced along with HTML in plain text format

Comment: @cruisepandey: Does this help? As I am not seeing any error with my initial attempt but is not interacting as I expect. Hence I was thinking to use JavaScriptExecutor and getComputedStyle for getting hold of Anchor Tag Element, but not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is **Java** bindings and all you want to do is to `click` on an achor tag which has `Raw view as a text`.

You could try with **ExplicitWaits** :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Raw View"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey. It was the click with JavaScript was the main problem. your above solution also worked. I continued with my old findby element, but changed click() from JavaScript click to normal click.